# Why won't my data save to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, save

So I'm trying to store some user information for a newsletter sign up form, and it works fine in XAMPP, but I've been having some trouble saving data to my live DB (GoDaddy). I also echoed out an error statement and it said that my query was empty, but I can't figure out why... Here is my code (the email duplication test also worked locally but doesn't anymore, obviously):

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//Log into the server
@ $db = mysql_pconnect("hostnamewashere", "usernamewashere", "pwwashere");

//Select the database desired
mysql_select_db("databasenamewashere");

//If no connection can be made, echo it out to the screen
if(!$db){
    echo "Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.";
exit;
}

//Retrieve data from form and create variables
$email = Trim(($_POST['email'])); 
$ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = ip2long($ip_orig);
$date = date('Y-m-d');  
$time = date('H:i:s');  

//Validate data
if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
$_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Please enter your email.";
Header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", ($_POST['email']))) { 
$_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Incorrect email format; please try again.";
Header("Location: index.php");
exit; 
}

//Check to see that no duplicates exist in the database
$sql = "SELECT newsletter_email FROM Newsletter WHERE newsletter_email='".$email."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(empty($result)) {
$num_results = 0;
}else {
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
}

if($num_results !== 0) {
$_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Sorry, that email address is already in our database.";
Header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}

//Place into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO Newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date,     newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', '".$ip."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";

//Run query and get result back; shouldn't return anything
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//Redirect user to successful registration page
Header("Location: index.php");
$_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Thanks! We will be in touch with you soon.";
exit;

//Close the database connection
mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: I cant say this enough, the amount of students I have that have similair problems.  Honestly in my opinion if you have a problem like this just comment out your $result = mysql_query($sql); and stick in an echo instead echo $sql; just to see what your actual query is that is being constructed.  Atleast to make sure if you are constructing valid sql.

Comment: Output the queries made and try them directly in PhpMyAdmin or MySQL console.

Comment: Are you sure your connection data is valid? (localhost,user,pass,db)

Comment: Yes, people just need to learn how to think problems out, and how to debug. StackOverflow is not a debugging tool. It is for when you've debugged to a point where you can no longer figure anything out for yourself.`</rant>`

Comment: I actually tried doing the insert in a manual query and got this as a result: 

#1146 - Table 'peoplocity.Newsletter' doesn't exist

The weird thing is the result showed up in my tables (and started storing the email address from the pg, but with duplicates), but now I'm unable to recreate the same thing...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart raises a good point... it's hard to help on problems like these without having your entire installed deployment, since often the problem lies in things not being setup at all (like tables, boilerplate data, etc.)  From what you've said it looks like you aren't using the correct table or haven't created it yet on the mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda rewrote the script, but the only thing that I really saw that threw an error for me was not having date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); set.

The below script works for me:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbname = 'test';

if ($_POST)
{

    //Retrieve data from form and create variables
    $email = trim($_POST['email']); 
    $ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip = ip2long($ip_orig);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');  

    //Validate data
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Please enter your email.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    }

    if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", ($_POST['email']))) { 
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Incorrect email format; please try again.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit; 
    }

    //Log into the server
    $db = @mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    //Select the database desired
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //If no connection can be made, echo it out to the screen
    if(!$db){
        echo "Error: Could not connect to the database. Please try again later.";
    exit;
    }

    //Check to see that no duplicates exist in the database
    $sql = "SELECT newsletter_email FROM Newsletter WHERE newsletter_email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Sorry, that email address is already in our database.";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }

    //Place into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', '".$ip."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";

    //Run query and get result back; shouldn't return anything
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    //Redirect user to successful registration page
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Thanks! We will be in touch with you soon.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;

    //Close the database connection
    mysql_close($db);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input name="email" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```